# animationlistener not working pre honeycomb devices

Tags: android, animation, listener, android-3.0-honeycomb

I want to apply an animation to a view and show it when the animation has ended through a AnimationListener. My code works for devices 4.x but it's not working for a 2.3.3 device, the onAnimationStart and onAnimationEnd methods are never called.

```
 final Animation toTopAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(), R.anim.move_up);
 toTopAnimation.setDuration(250);
 toTopAnimation.setFillBefore(true);
 toTopAnimation.setFillAfter(true);

 toTopAnimation.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {
     @Override
     public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
          Log.i("log", "onAnimationStart");
     }
     @Override
     public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
         Log.i("log", "onAnimationEnd");
         mQuickReturnView.setVisibility (View.VISIBLE);
     }

     @Override
     public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
     }
 });

  mQuickReturnView.setAnimation(toTopAnimation);
  mQuickReturnView.startAnimation(toTopAnimation);
```

Can you see anything wrong?

Thanks

Comment: the snippet looks good and it has  to work on pre honycomb devices too. Imo the issue releis everywhere else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar issue and managed to solve it. I'm still not really sure what's the reason behind this problem, but it's lying somewhere around the content of the view and the way gingerbread handles its drawing.

In my case I had a `RelativeLayout` which had some views in it. The animation would work only if I changed some value of a child view in my RelativeLayout before calling the animation. For example, I had a `TextView` inside, so I would call the `setText()` method. Maybe you should try it too:

```
// ---
mQuickReturnView.setAnimation(toTopAnimation);
someViewInsidemQuickReturnView.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.some_string));
mQuickReturnView.startAnimation(toTopAnimation);
// ---
```

The `setText()` method updates the view in some way and the animation works fine after that.

Comment: Thanks, setText() didn't work for me but the problem was similar. In my case I solved it by hiding some content in the layout.